# Expo Deep links : Do I provide the url of the website or the app scheme in email for a deep link?

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

When Im sending an email including a link to my app, do I send the url of my website 'www.example.com' which then redirects to my app?

When I parse and log the url:

`const { hostname, path, queryParams } = Linking.parse(url);`

then when the full url is: `http://www.example.com/confirm?code=abcd`

with website url I get:

host: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), path: confirm and queryParams: {"code": "abcd"}

when the url is when the full url is: `myAppScheme:///confirm?code=abcd`

I get host: confirm, path: null and queryParams: {"code": "abcd"}

Because of that a redirect to another screen does when I provide the website [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) doesnt work with:

```
  const linking = {
        prefixes: [prefix],
        config: {
            screens: {
                ConfirmAccount: {
                    path: "confirm",
                },
                NotFound: '*',
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your app will work better if you use the URL like *myAppScheme://confirm/abcd* (scheme://[path]/[parameter]), this way you can have a linking-config like:

```
const linking = {
        prefixes: [prefix],
        config: {
            screens: {
                ConfirmAccount: {
                    path: "/confirm/:id",
                },
                NotFound: '*',
            }
        },
```

And then you can capture the *id* using something like:

```
const TheComponent = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { id } = route.params;
}
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: then the deep link also doesnt work because when I open the link on my desktop, i am suppose to be redirected to my website as no app is installed but im not, its just a broken link